# Diagram Hasse partial with maximal-minimal -greatest-least element

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Check please and my draw if i it is right [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrvQu.jpg).I have A={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}.I should create Hasse diagram and find the maximal-minimal -greatest-least element.

```
as least element i put :1 
as greatest element i put:8
maximal:7,8
minimal:2,3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]
Hasse Diagram.

Minimal Elements $=2,3$

Maximal Elements $=5,6,7,8$

Comment: why maximal elements are 5,6,7,8 and there aren't only 7,8??

Comment: As you can see in the diagram,, maximal elements are those which are the end of the branch.

Comment: my diagram isn't right?cause i have seen it similar.

Comment: It's not because $3$ can be linked to $6$

Comment: thanks a lot man :)